How do changes in airspeed in a level, constant bank uncoordinated turn affect coordination?
I'm hurting my brain trying to understand how the PHAK talks about correcting slips and skids. I think part of my confusion comes from the fact that the formulas for rate and radius of turn assume a coordinated turn.
To paraphrase, the PHAK says that to correct a slipping turn, you can decrease bank angle, increase the Rate of Turn, or a combination of both.
I think some ways to increase Rate of Turn would be too input more inside rudder and/or apply more back stick pressure. Would another be increasing airspeed if bank angle is held constant (assuming a level turn)?
This goes against those formulas I mentioned, but like I said, I think know that they only apply to coordinated turns. Thanks

As Robert DiGiovanni said, normally you would use any combination of aileron/rudder to change your rate of turn. Yes, changes in pitch (and hence changes in total lift produced) also has an effect because it is a component of lift that pushes us in to the turn but in practical flying we would reserve pitch/power changes to correct for ALT/VS and aileron/rudder for turning.

Normally one corrects for a slipping turn with less aileron or more rudder (watch the ball).
Increasing the rate of turn could be accomplished by slowing down.

in the ROT formula speed is in the denominator

Since the plane is banked, more elevator input to pitch for lower speed also creates more inward (centripetal force) relative to the forward force (thrust) vector.

but slowing in a turn can be dangerous

Best to keep it simple.  Coordinate rudder and aileron.  Use power to control climb and descent.  Yes, it works in turns too.

Changing power setting in a single will also affect its rolling tendency, so one could theoretically "correct" a slipping right hand turn by adding power, but again, the go-to method of coordinating is $rudder$.
